# Create a 3 dimension view of a background image

Tags: android

I have a screen where I need to put a **background image**. I need to display only a  **part of the background image**  in each screen . Now when the user swipes towards left , the next screen will be displayed taking **another portion of the background image**. This **transition from the first to second screen should give a 3 Dimension effect of moving the screen**.
I am unable to get any help form Android forums.
Kindly help with the **code** .

Comment: check the ApiDemos package, there is something nice that looks like what you need in Views/animations/3D transitions

Comment: I am looking for a code to rotate the background image in a 3D

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve [Parallax Scrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling)?

If so, this looks like a good description of it being implemented in Android;

http://csjam.blogspot.com/2009/02/parallax-scrolling-in-android.html

Comment: I am looking for a code to rotate the background image in a 3D